# Grep Regex: How to find multiple area codes in phone number?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a file: each line consist of a name, room number, house address, phone number.

I want to search for the lines that have the area codes of either 404 or 202.
I did "(404)|(202)" but it also gives me lines that had the numbers in the phone number in general instead of from area code, example:

```
John Smith 300 123 N. Street 808-543-2029
```

I do not want the above, I am targeting lines like this, examples:

```
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 202-383-1540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404-653-1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat addresses
John Smith 202 404 N. Street 808-543-2029
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 202-383-1540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404-653-1200
```

The distinguishing feature of area codes, as opposed to other three digit numbers, is that they have a space  before them and a `-` after them.  Thus, use:

```
$ grep -E ' (202|404)-' addresses
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 202-383-1540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404-653-1200
```

#### More complex example

Suppose that phone numbers appear at the end of lines but can have any of the three forms `808-543-2029`, `8085432029`, or `808 543 2029` as in the following example:

```
$ cat addresses
John Smith 202 404 N. Street 808-543-2029
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 2023831540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404 653 1200
```

To select the lines with 202 or 404 area codes:

```
$ grep -E ' (202|404)([- ][[:digit:]]{3}[- ][[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{7})$' addresses
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 2023831540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404 653 1200
```

If it is possible that the phone numbers are followed by stray whitespaces, then use:

```
$ grep -E ' (202|404)([- ][[:digit:]]{3}[- ][[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{7})[[:blank:]]*$' addresses
Danny Brown 173 555 W. Avenue 2023831540
Martha Keith 567 322 S. Example 404 653 1200
```

Comment: Thanks! For future references, what expressions can we use if the phone numbers looked like 8085432029 for example. Or maybe 808 543 2029 as well

Comment: @Anymee Your welcome.  See the new section to the answer for examples of how to handle those alternative forms for phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a word boundary token `\b` right at the beginning of expression, such as `\b(202|404)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tzpmzf/1).

Comment: `\b` is supported by some `sed` dialects, but isn't properly portable.

Comment: You're right. I think we should rework then to match a phone number and, maybe, extract area code. But can we assume it is always formatted the same way?

Comment: The word boundary does nothing to prevent 404 Not Found Street from matching.